# What is the word for the action of overriding something?

Tags: phrase-requests

> Again this is a situation where you need to override an automatic camera and set the controls manually.

This is an example for the use of `Override`. I had to use a word for the action of overriding something today, and couldn't think of a word.

I imagined a possibility for the word, but couldn't find it in any dictionary:

- Overridance

So for instance, for the sentence above, something close to the following is desired:

> Again this is a situation where you need to enable the ***overridance*** of the automatic camera and set the controls manually.

Is there such a word in English, or am I overcomplicating the sentence?

Comment: I would simply use the gerund "overriding", in the same way I would talk of "...need to enable the *cleaning*/*dismantling*/*setting-up* of the automatic camera". We wouldn't say *cleanance* would we? It is ***"the overriding"***.

Comment: @WS2: I'd stick to a plain infinitive (same as following ***set***) and discard the pointlessly verbose ***enable the*** and ***of*** - leaving just *you need to **override** the automatic camera*.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers But there is a difference between 'needing to override' and 'needing to enable the overriding' isn't there?

Comment: I think you might be overcomplicating the sentence. The selection of manual or auto is commonly a toggle (an either/or choice). If so, then "Again this is a situation where you need to *toggle from auto to manual* and set the controls yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple rule of plain English.  It it to avoid abstract nouns if you possibly can.  They are overused.  If at all possible, use the active verb with a concrete and, if relevant, personal  subject.  People imagine it is more intelligent to use long latinate abstract nouns.  It isn’t.

Comment: But is overridance a correct term? I know it shouldn't be used, but in this exact situation I thought it would be a better word

Comment: No, ‘overridance’ is not standard English.   One reason is that ‘-nce’ endings are derived from Latin via French.  ‘Override’ is derived from the Teutonic heritage of the English language.

Comment: You can, in fact, use ‘override’ as a noun:  “enabling the automatic override” is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The noun form of the verb *override* is [***override***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/override). From Oxford Dictionaries (scroll down to see the noun definition):

> 1. A device for suspending an automatic function on a machine.
>      *‘the flash has to have a manual override to be useful’*

(Senses 2 and 3 of the noun correspond to other uses of the verb.)

So in your sentence, you would say

> Again this is a situation where you need to enable the **override** of the automatic camera and set the controls manually.

Or, more succinctly:

> Again this is a situation where you need to *engage the manual **override*** of the camera.